# Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: mismatched tag: line 7, column 4

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using kinetic version of ROS. I am a very new user to ROS. So I was trying to write a launch code that would launch two different launch files. One launch file is of husky_gazebo package, the other one is for teleop_twist_keyboard package. I am not sure if I can write a code that can launch these files together.
For my launch file I am getting following error:

```
Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: mismatched tag: line 7, column 4
```

below is my launch file:

```
<launch>

<include file="$(find husky_gazebo)/launch/husky_empty_world.launch">
<arg name="world_name" value="$(find gazebo-7)/worlds/robocup14_spl_field.world">
<arg name="laser_enabled" value="$(arg laser_enabled)"/>
<arg name="kinect_enabled" value="$(arg kinetic_enabled)"/>
</include>

<include file="$(find teleop_twist_keyboard)/teleop_twist_keyboard.py">
</include>

</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/293064/invalid-roslaunch-xml-syntax:-mismatched-tag:-line-7,-column-4/) by [Swag10](https://answers.ros.org/users/35462/swag10/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2018-06-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to change your first `<arg>` tag to be a self-closing tag `<arg/>`:

```
<arg name="world_name" value="$(find gazebo-7)/worlds/robocup14_spl_field.world"/>
```

Also, the `<include>` tag is for including other XML files: Check out the [documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/include):

> The `<include>` tag enables you to import another roslaunch XML file into the current file...

You want to use the `<node>` tag instead to launch that node:

```
<node name="teleop_twist_keyboard" pkg="teleop_twist_keyboard" type="teleop_twist_keyboard.py"/>
```

So, your final launch file will look like

```
<launch>

<include file="$(find husky_gazebo)/launch/husky_empty_world.launch">
<!-- this tag below -->
<arg name="world_name" value="$(find gazebo-7)/worlds/robocup14_spl_field.world"/>
<arg name="laser_enabled" value="$(arg laser_enabled)"/>
<arg name="kinect_enabled" value="$(arg kinetic_enabled)"/>
</include>

<node name="teleop_twist_keyboard" pkg="teleop_twist_keyboard" type="teleop_twist_keyboard.py"/>

</launch>
```

Please see the [documentation for the `<node>` tag](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node).

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Swag10](https://answers.ros.org/users/35462/swag10/) on 2018-06-04**:
Oh so sorry. It was a silly mistake.
It is working now.
Thanks a lot.